# Set opacity on background-image with media query

Tags: javascript, css

I have a couple of divs, each with a background image. I'm using responsive and adaptive CSS, and when my divs' widths gets **less than** a certain size(760px btw), the text and some tables with styling becomes hard to read/see with the background image moving in behind them(the background image is on the far right of the text/tables and unobtrusive if the width is **above** 760px...). So when the width of the viewport gets to 760px and less, I only want the background image to have an opacity...

How do I do that?

So my CSS starts like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
   background: #cdcdcd url("/images/back.jpg") no-repeat top right;
    /*How do I set the opacity of only the background?*/
}
```

Comment: you cannot dynamically change the opacity of a background image; you would need two separate images, one being a transparent PNG with the desired opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the opacity of a background image, unless you move it to a separate container.

All you can change is the opacity of BG color using `rgba()`:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

Comment: thank you, but that is a problem...my background image is set with inline styling and I cannot change that due to a custom jquery function requiring it...so the only option then is to get different background images (whose opacity is set on the image itself) and use javascript to change the inline style of the elements, right? Using a if $('#myID').outerWidth(value, function(){}) function to change the styling?

Comment: you can do this - http://jsfiddle.net/mj5by/  when your window is less than 760px you remove the BG attribute and insert an absolutely positioned image in `<div>` instead with applied opacity

Comment: nice, like your solution, kinda thing I was looking for...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't set opacity just for a background, but the whole element. You can set opacity of background **color** (see [**Zoltan's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993279/1494505) for the example).

---

You can set white `<div>` over the image and change it's opacity.

```
<div class="yourImage">
    <div class="imageCover"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.yourImage {
  background: url(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png);
  width: 300px;
  height: 83px;
}
.imageCover {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 83px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/fu1NtHdj)**

*However, this won't work if you don't have a clean background BEHIND your image.*

Comment: Ok thank you. Not what I was looking for but good answer nonetheless. You see the problem is that the the bg image is behind text, and setting opacity the way you suggest will make the text fade out as well, the reason I want the image to fade in the first place - Because the text is unreadable with the bg image behind it...

Comment: best thing then is to just remove the bg image when I get to my 'backgroundImage-messing-up-text' width...